# Find closest date to current date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that activates the first cell that is the current date or closest to it in a column.

I tried this:

```
Cells.Find(What:=Date, After:=Range("B6"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Which works only if the current date is somewhere in the column, but if it is not then I get an error. How do I modify it to keep searching until it find the closest date to the current date?

Comment: Before the current date, after the current date or absolute closest? Are the dates sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looping through a progressive series of additions and subtractions to the current date, a short sub section of your procedure can determine the date that you are looking for.

```
Sub nearest_date()
    Dim b As Range, lr As Long, iMaxDiff As Long, d As Long, fndDate

    With ActiveSheet  'set this worksheet properly!
        With .Range(.Cells(6, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            iMaxDiff = Application.Min(Abs(Application.Max(.Cells) - Date), Abs(Date - Application.Min(.Cells)))
            For d = 0 To iMaxDiff
                If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Cells, Date + d)) Then
                    fndDate = Date + d
                    Exit For
                ElseIf CBool(Application.CountIf(.Cells, Date - d)) Then
                    fndDate = Date - d
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next d
            Set b = .Find(What:=fndDate, After:=Range("B6"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            'do something with the closest date. I do NOT recommend using .Select for anything beyond demonstration purposes
            b.Select
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This is a passive way to determine the closest date. Once found, we know it is there and questionable coding practices like `On Error Resume Next` can be avoided. TBH, once you *know* is it there, an `application.Match` could locate it just as easily.

Comment: This worked great for the first sheet in the workbook, but when I added a sheet and needed to perform the same search it gave me an error at the "b.Select" part towards the end. I thought ActiveSheet at the beginning would allow me to use the code throughout the workbook, but there seems to be a problem extending it to other sheets beyond the initial one. Any suggestions?

Comment: You would need some sort of loop outside the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Something like `for w = 1 to sheets.count` then `with worksheets(w)`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop and evaluate every other date in the column (since the closets date might be in the farthest cell). Assuming that you have two dates in the column that are equally "close", you could then pick the nearest one (cell-wise).

There is no way to do this with the `Find` method. You'll have to create loop through each cell in the column.