# Find closest Date to specific Date

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Tables.

Table1 goes from A1:F10 and shows the machine assignment.
Table2 goes from G1:K10 and shows the storage for the machines.

With a button I want to simulate which storage should be used for which machine.

In column C stands the date when the machine has to be built. In Column I stands the date when the storage is ready to use.

For example: The first machine has to start on 08/15/2018. How can I check which date in Column I is the closest to 08/15/2018?

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lastrow as Long

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    for a = 1 to lastrow
        If Cells(a, 1) = "Machine Name" And _    ' Find the specific machine
        Cells(a, 4) = "" Then                    ' In this cell the serial number of the storage should be added
            ' Now check if Storage for this machine is ready to use.
            For b = 1 to lastrow
                If Cells(b, 8) = "123" And _    ' Serial Number of the Storage
                Cells(b, 10) = "" Then          ' In this Cell serial number of the machine should be added
                    ' Here it should check which Date in Column I is the closest to the date in Column C
                    Cells(a, 4).Value = Cells(b, 8)
                    Cells(b, 10).Value = Cells(a, 2)
               End If
           Next b
       End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

I tried to change the code from [Find closest date to current date in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764899/find-closest-date-to-current-date-in-vba).

In the picture you can see an example how the table looks:

[image]

Comment: Define "closest".  Perhaps you could give a few examples? Does over/under matter? (ie, if the machine has to start 8/15/2018 then what if both the 16th and 14th are in the list to check?)

Comment: And what is the way you want it? Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to crreate an example

Comment: @ashleedawg sorry, so that the storage can be used the storage date in column I has to be before the start date in column C. The date in Column I shows when a storage is ready to use and the date in Column C shows when the workers has to start to build the machine.

Comment: @Storax in the picture you can see my tables. Now i want that if i click the button it checks when "Maschine A" starts, then it should look in Column I which Date is the closest before 15.06.2018 (Sorry .. dateformat is German DD/MM/JJJJ)

Comment: For a = 1 to lastrow.....where do you get lastrow from in your code? Also, it feels like this could be done through formulas.

Comment: @JvdV .. just forgot to type it in. Now lastrow is in the code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't specify where you want the closest date before start so i just added the date as a comment to the start date in column C.

```
Sub FindClosestBeforeDate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lLastReadyUsed As Long
    Dim lLastStartUsed As Long
    Dim dt As String
    Dim temp As Variant

    Set ws = Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lLastStartUsed = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    lLastReadyUsed = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    'Delete previous comments
    For l = 2 To lLastStartUsed
        If Not Range("c" & l).Comment Is Nothing Then
            ws.Range("C" & l).Comment.Delete
        End If
    Next l

    'add comments with closeste date before startdate
    For l = 2 To lLastStartUsed
        For i = 2 To lLastReadyUsed
            If DateDiff("D", ws.Range("C" & l).value, ws.Range("I" & i).value) < 0 Then
                If IsEmpty(temp) Then
                    temp = DateDiff("D", ws.Range("C" & 3).value, ws.Range("I" & i).value)
                    dt = ws.Range("I" & i).value
                ElseIf temp < DateDiff("D", ws.Range("C" & 3).value, ws.Range("I" & i).value) Then
                    temp = DateDiff("D", ws.Range("C" & 3).value, ws.Range("I" & i).value)
                    dt = ws.Range("I" & i).value
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        temp = Empty
        ws.Range("C" & l).AddComment dt
    Next l
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you out

Answer (score 0):

With your example, im assuming you want

2. Start = 15.06.2018, Ende = 14.03.2018
3. Start = 25.08.2018, Ende = 26.07.2018

Add this Function and call it like `YourCell.Value = getClosestDateBefore(StartCell.Value, Range("I2:I9"))`

```
Function getClosestDateBefore(d As Date, RefDateRange As Range) As Date
    Dim i As Long, ref_date As Date, diff As Double, best_diff As Double
    best_diff = -10000000
    With RefDateRange
        For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
            ref_date = .Cells(i).Value2
            diff = ref_date - d
            If diff < 0 And diff > best_diff Then
                best_diff = diff
                getClosestDateBefore = ref_date
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: The part `For i = 1 To DateRange.Cells.Count` causes the error "object needed". I am not sure which range here is needed.

Comment: oh right. i forgot i called it `RefDateRange`. edited